# Java - Synchronize Threads on certain point

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to synchronize some threads at a certain checkpoint, and only after all threads have reached this point, they should continue. Is there any easy construct?

```
for (int v = 0; v < 10; v++) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                doFirst();

                //checkpoint

                doSecond();

            } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Check out CyclicBarrier, CountDownLatch and deadlock.

Comment: Following up on that, `try { ... } finally { latch.countDown(); }` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the exact number of your threads you can use [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) from java.util.concurrent.

```
 // First initialize latch with your number of threads
 CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(N);

 // Then give this instance of latch to each of your threads

 // and finally at your checkpoint do
 latch.countDown();
 latch.await();
```

That's all.

Comment: seems to be the shortest solution, i'll try that

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
private CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(10)
...
public void run() {
    doFirst();
    countDownLatch.countDown();
    countDownLatch.await();
    doSecond();
}
```

---- OR (1 less line of code) ----

```
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
private CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier= new CyclicBarrier(10)
...
public void run() {
    doFirst();
    cyclicBarrier.await();
    doSecond();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a lock object:

```
Integer threadCount = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
{
    new Thread(() ->
    {
        try
        {
            doFirst();
            synchronized (threadCount)
            {
                threadCount--;
                while (threadCount > 0)
                    threadCount.wait();
                threadCount.notifyAll();
            }
            doSecond();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }).start();
}

// all threads are started, to wait until they've finished, call threadCount.wait();
```

Comment: That's what a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch does.

Comment: @jameslarge Didn't know that such a class exists, but great to know that Oracle suggest the same thing to do :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to synchronize your threads over a common monitor:

```
Object monitor = new Object();
int jobCount = 0;

public void f1(){
 for (int v = 0; v < 10; v++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                doFirst();
                check();    

                doSecond();

                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

public void sleep(){}

public void check(){
    synchronized(monitor){
       jobCount++;
       if(jobCount==10){
           monitor.notifyAll();
           return;
       }
    }
    monitor.wait();
}
```

Things to consider:

1. When you call monitor.wait(), the thread where that invocation was made will go to sleep, synchronized over monitor
2. notifyAll() will awaken all threads that are sleeping and synch. over its recipient.
3. When one thread enters a synchronized block, it will take a lock over monitor. notifyAll() can only be invoked if a lock exists on its recipient